# merge properties files of two modules in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, properties

I have a `Maven` project with multiple modules. Module ModuleB uses ModuleA as an internal Maven dependency. In moduleA I have a `Spring` xml config module.a.xml that loads a module.a.properties file. In the `Spring` xml config of moduleB I import the module.b.properties file together with the module.a.xml config.

In the end I end up with a `Spring` xml config with two property file imports. Depending of the order of the imports I can only access properties of one file: either module.a.properties or module.b.properties. How can I use both properties at the same time?

The problem with a solution using the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is that the properties files reside at different modules and moduleB shouldn't worry about a properties file of moduleA.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="corePlaceHolder">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:modula.a.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:modula.b.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem with using `ignore-unresolvable="true"` is that a forgotten property can easily be missed and putting `ignore-unresolvable="true"` on the `property-placeholder` can easily be missed.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="module.a.properties" order="0" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="module.b.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can solve your problem but, since you are using a maven multi-module build, have you considered suing a maven plugin to create a third properties file as a merge of A and B with proper override strategy?

Here is a sample using [maven-merge-properties-plugin](https://github.com/javanto/maven-merge-properties-plugin)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.beardedgeeks</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-merge-properties-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <merges>
      <merge>
        <targetFile>${moduleB.output.dir}/module-final.properties</targetFile>
        <propertiesFiles>
          <propertiesFile>${moduleB.src.dir}/moduleB.properties</propertiesFile>
          <propertiesFile>${moduleA.src.dir}/moduleA.properties</propertiesFile>
        </propertiesFiles>
      </merge>
    </merges>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>merge</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this way you will get all A and B properties in just on file. If a property exists on both A and B, B will win (check file order in configuration).

Being both modules in the same project retrieve both files should be quite easy.
You could even use another plugin to unpack just needed properties files from external jars.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution requires to 1) know there is a proporties file 2) know the name of the proporties file. I just want to use an append on the new proporties without knowing anything about the internals of moduleA. ModulA could have been in an external dependency for the sake of argument

Comment: Ok, you are trying to achieve a higher abstraction level, so you want to work at code level instead of a build one.
As told in the answer, being the module an external dependencies could easily be addressed with a dependency-unpack plugin.
About point 1/2 you have to know in any case since you are including them into your spring conf. If you want to move some effort into **build** section, I'm expecting your pom be aware of files existence, leaving the **dev** part be unaware of it, since the output file would be however into your classpath so no extra-exfort needed in spring file.

Comment: I don't have to know about the properties file existence. The properties file is including with a spring xml import. I don't want to change every pom file that uses moduleA with some hacky code. I don't understand why something so simple and intuitive seems impossible. Spring can append the properties of the new property file to the existing properties with ease...Should be able to configure the default behaviour of Spring somewhere...